# Coding issue with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the coding world and currently in school studying however I seem to have run into an issue I just can't figure out. I'm trying to run my index.js file using the terminal but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\salij\OneDrive\Desktop\U2A\index
'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing because looking at the steps that I've been given I shouldn't be receiving this error. Here is my code in case anyone could lend me a hand. TIA

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express ()
const formidable = require ('formidable')

app.use(express.static (__dirname + "/WebCalculatorSolution/WebCalculator"))

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{

const word = req.query.word
   res.write('<h1>${word}</h1>')
   res.end()
})



const port = 8000
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Server ready at: http://localhost:${port}')
})
```

Comment: @prathameshmore Thank you for your comments. I have tried the below methods you and the others have suggested but I still seem to be receiving the same error. I already have express and formidable installed but just in case I installed them once more to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to install npm packages

`npm install express formidable`

All packages will be installed after running this command

As per your code, you are trying to display words when the user passes from the query.

You have to template string, so you can directly embed variables in a string.

You can do this.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const formidable = require('formidable')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/WebCalculatorSolution/WebCalculator"))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let word;
  word = req.query.word ? req.query.word : "Welcome"; //If word won't passed then show welcome message else show word
  res.write(`<h1>${word}</h1>`)
  res.end()
})

const port = 8000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server ready at: http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Without query parameter

[image: Run without query params]

Passing query params

[image: Passing query params]

Answer (score 0):

The correct Template literals syntax is wrapping your text with backticks (``), modify this line:

```js
`Server ready at: http://localhost:${port}`
```

Also this line:

```js
`<h1>${word}</h1>`
```

Answer (score 0):

install the package with the command:
`npm install formidable`.
Then run the server

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find my issue. Running cmd in Visual Studio Code I noticed that it was trying to run my index file from a completely different location in file explorer. After I directed it to the folder where my index file was actually located it finally started working without issue. Thank you all for your help.